# how to update cart subtotal after change item price with observer magento 1.8

Tags: cart, upgrade

[image]

```
$aPost  = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getPost();
         $id = $aPost['product'];

         $qty = $aPost['qty'];
         $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($id);
         $bundleType = $product->getTypeId();
         if ($bundleType == 'bundle') {
         $collection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection($product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product), $product);
         $itemIds = array();
         $b=0;
         $n=1;

         foreach ($collection as $item) {

             if($n == 1) {$price = $item->getPrice();}
             $sku = $item->getSku();
             if($sku = 'shoose01') {
                 $b=20;
             } elseif ($sku = 'shoose01') {
                 $b=30;
             } elseif ($sku = 'simple2122'){
                 $b=40;
             } elseif ($sku = 'moniteur24'){ 
               $b=60;
             } else {
                $b=0; 
             }
             $n++;
         } 
         }
            $single_price = $price+$b;


$single_price=50;
if($bundleType == 'bundle') {       
            $item->setCustomPrice($single_price);   
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($single_price);
             }
```

Use of `setCustomPrice()` and `setOriginalCustomPrice()` functions for only single product amount and grand total amount updating , but not updating sub total of single item as well sub total of all amount.

Check above Screen Shot.

if you have any solution. Then let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
{
    $quote = $obs->getCart()->getQuote();
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $bundleitems) {
        $sku = $bundleitems->getSku();
        if ($sku == 'hdb005') {
            $single_price=50;
            $item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($bundleitems->getId());
            $product_id = $item->getProductId();
            $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
            $item->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());
            $item->setCustomPrice($single_price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($single_price);
            $item->setProduct($product);
            $item->save();
            //for updating the totals
            $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
            $quote->collectTotals()->save();
        }
        if ($sku == 'hdb007') {
            $single_price=60;
            $item= Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($bundleitems->getId());
            $product_id = $item->getProductId();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
            $item->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());
            $item->setCustomPrice($single_price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($single_price);
            $item->setProduct($product);
            $item->save();
            //for updating the totals
            $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
            $quote->collectTotals()->save();
        }
    }
}
```

with this event `checkout_cart_save_after`

Answer (score 1):

use quote collectTotals method

`$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();`

Comment: this solution is not working for me , updating Grand total but not sub total